# Calculate date php issue with strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Still trying to figure out date with PHP. I have this:

```
$fri_end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Friday'));
$fri_start_date = date('Y-m-d ',strtotime('Friday'));
$put = $fri_start_date.$fri_end_date;
echo "$put";
```

I want to calculate the date for each Friday but display that Friday date through till Sunday.  Then on Monday it would show the next coming Friday.  Basically want to show the same Friday date throughout the weekend.  How would I do this?

Comment: sorry I'm bit confuse here with question. can you please simplify lil bit? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did understand your question now and I think this will solve your issue:

```
if( date('w') >= 6 ) 
   $fri_end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Friday'));
else
  $fri_start_date = date('Y-m-d ',strtotime('Friday'));

$put = $fri_start_date.$fri_end_date;
echo "$put";
```

Using date('w') will return you the day of the week, that way you can test if it is saturday or sunday and use the 'last Friday' or else use the "current" Friday.

Cheers,
Denis

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it is what you want:

```
$fri_end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Friday'));
$fri_start_date = date('Y-m-d ',strtotime('next Friday'));
$put = $fri_start_date.$fri_end_date;
echo "$put";
```

This will display the date of the last Friday before the day you run the code and the next Friday.

Cheers,
Denis

Comment: This is showing to large a range.  The end_date and start_date should always be the same Friday value when outputted. At least that's what I need.  Not sure it can be done.  Perhaps some if..else statement or some sort could handle it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not really clear about your problem. That sayd, if I understand correctly you need to display 2 days before and after the current Friday. If that is the case try the code below.

```
$fri_end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Friday -2 days'));
$fri_start_date = date('Y-m-d ',strtotime('Friday +2days'));
$put = $fri_start_date.$fri_end_date;
echo "$put";
```

If it is not, try to be more concise and maybe throw in an example or two ;)

Cheers,
Denis

Comment: I need to output only the one day (Friday). For example this Friday 2011-11-18. This is easy with `strtotime('Friday')`.  However once Sat arrives it will show the next Friday.  I need 2011-11-18 echoed until end of Sunday, at which point only then will it show the next Friday. Clear as mud?